# AS3 Remove items in an ENTER_FRAME

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have generated random bubbles, I used a code I found in the net. Now I want a click event that will hide a random bubble.

Here is exactly the code I used,

http://good-tutorials-4u.blogspot.com/2009/04/flash-bubbles-with-actionscript-3.html

I got the bubbles running good...

I have tried this, and so far no luck..

```
addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, eventListener);


function eventListener(eventObject:MouseEvent) {

        bubbles[i].splice(i,1,bubbles[i]);

}
```

I tried using an array but it returns me this output
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
    at Function/()

TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
    at Function/()

Answer (score 2):

If you have the bubbles in an array this should work.

```
var randomIndex:int = int(Math.random() * bubbles.length);
parent.removeChild(bubbles[randomIndex]);
bubbles.splice(randomIndex, 1);
```

Notice that you have to remove the bubble from the display list too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a new array without a random element from the original array. Then just reassign the old array to the new one, e.g.

```
// get the random index to remove element at
var randomIndex:int = 0 + bubbles.length * Math.random();
var index:int = 0;

// create new array containing all apart from the chosen one
var newBubbles:Array = [];
for each (var item:Object in bubbles) {
    if (index != randomIndex) {
        newBubbles.push(item);
    }
    index++;
}

// here you go new array without one random item
bubbles = newBubbles;
```

Or something like these.

Comment: Although this works, it's using extra CPU time and memory to generate the new array (a list of pointers, so not a huge deal I guess).  Also if you're depending on modifying an incoming array parameter by reference then replacing the array doesn't work out (you instead have to return the new array from the function and assign it over the original in the place the function is called... it gets cumbersome).  That said this answer works and is a simpler approach sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Just a minor revision on Baris Usakli's code here, this is if you want the one that was clicked on to be removed.

```
var bubbles:Array = [];
function makeBubbles()
{
    for(var i:int=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        var bubble:Bubble = new Bubble();
        bubbles.push(bubble);
        addChild(bubble);
        bubble.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, eventListener);
     }
}


function eventListener(eventObject:MouseEvent) {

    var clickedBubbleIndex:int = bubbles.indexOf(eventObject.currentTarget);
    parent.removeChild(eventObject.currentTarget);
    bubbles.splice(clickedBubbleIndex:int, 1);

}
```

Comment: thanks! I've tried this first, and this appears in the output box

TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.
 at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
 at Function/<anonymous>()

Comment: well my code assumes two major things, that bubbles contains the display objects (movie clips or sprites) that have click handlers registered on them

Comment: I'm getting an error in this line,     bubbles.splice(clickedBubbleIndex:int, 1);   says Error: expecting rightparen before colon

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
bubbles.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, eventListener); // place this listener in moveBubbles function.

function eventListener(eventObject:MouseEvent):void {

     eventObject.currentTarget.visible = false;

}
```